# Is there a way to escape the # for siege?

Tags: angularjs, load-testing, stress-testing, siege

I have a url that contains a hash symbol "#". It's angular so I don't know if it can get escaped or at least I haven't found anything. I know I could ask the devs to fix it (https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) but I was just curious if there was a way to escape the hashtag within a url file. Sucks that # is the comments for siege.

Answer (score 0):

On Angular you can remove the hash symbol of all urls by enabling html mode on your app.config. Like in the code below:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.config([ '$locationProvider', function( $locationProvider ) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );

}])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was hoping to see if it was possible to escape the hashtag within the actual url file when using siege. I know it's possible to remove the "#" within angular.